# SSRS export to Excel in high (dpi) quality

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, pdf, ssrs-2016

I know there are numerous articles concerning the topic of exporting from SSRS to PDF/Image/Excel. Yet none seem to be quite up-to-date (2018).

Is there any way to export from SSRS to PDF/Excel in such a way that charts aren't of bad quality? The chart is readable, yet it hurts the eyes to focus on it.

"Fixes" that don't work:
- Change the DPI settings in the reportserver config
- Change the size of the chart
- Don't export to Excel/PDF

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Often this is not actually the report/PDF that is the issue. I get clear, sharp charts exporting to a PDF. Try zooming the PDF on screen, if that looks OK, printing the PDF, it should look fine. If it does then it's either the screen resolution or the PDF reader you are using.

I use Nitro PDF and the PDF's look fine. here's a screen shot of a chart, (zoomed in)

[image]

Nothing special was done to create this chart or render it.

The only time I get issues is if I use images, but using high res images fixes that.